# How to reuse connections between CORS Preflight & Resource Request?

Tags: javascript, angular, aws-lambda, cors

I use AWS HTTP API with Lambda Proxy Integration. API Gateway doesn't support CORS configuration for Lambda Proxy (Don't question this without knowing). So, I use same lambda to serve CORS Preflight response.

```js
if(event.routeKey.startsWith('OPTIONS') {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    // CORS Headers
    };
}

// Code for main methods like POST
```

(I use payload format version 2.0 of API Gateway Proxy Event)

To connect to the API, I use Angular. Although, I make only one request in the code, my API receives two requests which is expected. But, I am not sure an extra request is made by Angular or the browser itself. In any case, I want to have full control over CORS Preflight request. How to do this?

The reason I want to do this is because HTTP API sends `coonection: keep-alive` header and yet the resource request doesn't use the same connection. The result is: If userA has warmed up the lambda (cold start) in CORS Preflight request, userB can steal the effort by luck and userA might need to warm up new lambda which brings two cold start on the table: One for CORS Preflight and another for Resource Request.

How to reuse the same connection with which CORS Preflight was performed?

Comment: what your asking can't be done in the front end, the CORS Preflight request is made by the browser itself and not angular. You need to add some server logic to resolve this issue. I would like to ask you to remove the angular tag because your problem has nothing to do with  angular.

Answer (score -1):

You said:

> API Gateway doesn't support CORS configuration for Lambda Proxy

That's not true. I've enabled CORS for my endpoints without starting a Lambda function.

The following CloudFormation snippet created the `OPTIONS` method for my `Resource` in API gateway that would return a proper CORS response.

```yaml
MyOptionsMethod:
  Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
  Properties:
    ApiKeyRequired: false
    AuthorizationType: None
    HttpMethod: OPTIONS
    Integration:
      Type: MOCK
      IntegrationResponses:
      - StatusCode: 200
        ResponseParameters:
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'Content-Type,X-Api-Key,Access-Control-Allow-Origin'"
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "'POST,OPTIONS'"
          method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
        ResponseTemplates:
          application/json: ""
      PassthroughBehavior: NEVER
      RequestTemplates:
        application/json: '{"statusCode": 200}'
    MethodResponses:
    - StatusCode: 200
      ResponseModels:
        application/json: "Empty"
      ResponseParameters:
        method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: true
        method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods: true
        method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
    ResourceId: !Ref MyResource
    RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
```

If you do this for your API Gateway resource, CORS will be enabled and you will not need to execute a Lambda function just for CORS response.

Comment: You've added another method which is what I am already doing. What I meant to say by API Gateway not supporting CORS for proxy is that CORS configuration of API Gateway is not applicable to proxy.

Comment: Second, even your OPTIONS method won't work because lambda proxy still needs to return some CORS headers as part of CORS specs.

Comment: Third, I am talking about HTTP API (v2) not Rest API (v1), so I can't create mock integration to handle preflight. So, I have to use lambda to handle preflight.

Comment: Fourth, I asked about reusing connection, not how to handle CORS which is what I am successfully doing.